# How to replace occurrences of a string by elements of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a template string:

```
const template = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and answer to {question} must be {4}";
```

and an array of values:

```
const array = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"];
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to replace each occurrence of `{question}` by an element of my `array`, respecting the index, and preserving the braces. Result string should look like that:

```
"Answer to {Is it late?} must be {YES} and answer to {What time is it} must be {4}"
```

I have the notion that it is achievable with `replace`, or with `split` and `join`, but I don't manage to make it work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const template_string = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and for {question} it's {4}";
const things = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"]; // This is to be empty.
const result = template_string.replace(/(?<={)question(?=})/mg, _ => things.shift());
console.log(things); // Been empty
console.log(result);
```

**[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) supports a regular expression for things to be matched.** You may use lookbehind and lookahead to match `question` within the brackets; and `m` for multi-line support, `g` for multiple matches. And **it also accepts a function for generating the replaced ones**; I used an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) here.

Note that [regular expression lookbehind assertion in Javascript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) is **a proposal on *Stage 4***; it requires quite modern engines (Chrome 62+ supports it.). If that bothers you, the look- stuff is optional; you may use the below instead.

```
const result = template_string.replace(/\{question\}/mg, _ => `{${things.shift()}}`);
```

---

For you, I give you easy-to-opt ones.

```js
const template_string = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and for {question} it's {4}";
const things = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"];

function go_with_lookbehind(template_string, things)
{
 const the_things = Array.from(things);
 const result = template_string.replace(
  /(?<={)question(?=})/mg,
  _ => the_things.shift()
 );
 return result;
}

function go_without_lookbehind_but_a_template_literal(template_string, things)
{
 const the_things = Array.from(things);
 const result = template_string.replace(
  /\{question\}/mg,
  _ => `{${the_things.shift()}}`
 );
 return result;
}

function go_without_lookbehind_and_a_template_literal(template_string, things)
{
 const the_things = Array.from(things);
 const result = template_string.replace(
  /\{question\}/mg,
  _ => ('{' + the_things.shift() + '}')
 );
 return result;
}

console.info(go_with_lookbehind(template_string, things));
console.info(go_without_lookbehind_but_a_template_literal(template_string, things));
console.info(go_without_lookbehind_and_a_template_literal(template_string, things));

console.info("template_string: ", template_string); // Unchanged
console.info("things: ", things); // Unchanged
```

Comment: Your regex requires simple fix. Replace with: const result = template_string.replace(/(\{question\})/mg, _ => things.shift());

Comment: @MuhammadUzairKhan Curly braces are part of the regular expression syntax: `(thing){(a number)}`. And _V8_ engine is fairly smart that it does not consider `{(a non-numeric)}` as part of the syntax: `/{question}/mg` works as I expected anyway. However, you're right; the _good_ practice is escaping such characters no matter what. I'll make an edit for it.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I did not know `replace` could support a function as param. Can you put the solution **without lookbehind** first? For the lazy readers. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I will not use template litterals but strings instead, to support mini-/uglification: `'{'+things.shift()+'}'`

Comment: @RaphaMex Then `go_without_lookbehind_and_a_template_literal` is for you.

Answer (score 2):

A possibly simpler solution can be:

```
let counter = 0
const template = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and answer to {question} must be {4}";
const array = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"];

let temp = template

// we are checking two things here
// 1. Whether the string contains the {question} or not
// 2. Whether the array index exists or not

while (temp.includes('{question}') && typeof array[counter] !== 'undefined') {
temp = temp.replace('{question}', `{${array[counter]}}`);
counter++;
}

console.log(temp);

//Answer to {Is it late?} must be {YES} and answer to {What time is it?} must be {4}
```

You can simply have a while condition on the string to see if it contains {question} or not. If it exists and the array index exists then replace the clause with the one in the array.

The extra checks are in place to handle exceptions. If you are sure that the number of instances of {question} will be the same as the number of elements in the array then you can remove the checks.

Comment: You may use `String.prototype.includes` for the `.contains`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const template = 'Answer to {question} must be {YES} and answer to {question} must be {4}';
const questions = ['Is it late?', 'What time is it?'];

document.write(template.split('{question}').map((chunk, index) => `${chunk}${index < questions.length ? `{${questions[index]}}` : ''}`).join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does this. It will replace the {question} as long as there is a respective index in the array

```
    function replaceCurlies(str,arr,seprator){
      var temp_arr=str.split(seprator);
      var ret=[];
      for(var i=0;i<temp_arr.length;i++){
        if(i<arr.length)
          ret.push(temp_arr[i]+"{"+arr[i]+"}")
        else
          ret.push(temp_arr[i])
      }
      return ret.join()
    }

    const array = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"];
    const template = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and answer to {question} must be {4}";
    console.log(replaceCurlies(template,array,"{question}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert `string` into `array of string` and then pass it through `map` and convert the required places and then re-convert the `array of string` into `string`.

```
const array = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"];
const template = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and answer to {question} must be {4}";
let arr = template.split(' ');
let i=0;
arr = arr.map(value=>{
  if(value==='{question}')
    {
      value = `{${array[i]}}`;
      i++;
    }
    else
      value = value
  return value
});
arr = arr.join(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `template.split('{question}')` does a better job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function merge(left,right) {
  var result = [];
  var index = 0;
  var length = left.length;

  while (index < length) {
     result.push(left[index]);
     if(right[index]){ //since array lenghts are not equal
       result.push(right[index]);
     }

     index++;
  }
  return result;
}

const template = "Answer to {question} must be {YES} and answer to {question} must be {4}";
const array = ["Is it late?", "What time is it?"];

var arraySplit = template.split("{question}");
var allArray = merge(arraySplit,array);
var resStr =  allArray.join();
```